# How much of a sphere will be submerged into a fluid?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, physics

I found this problem in a study guide and I've been stuck at it:

> Suppose that a hollow spherical object of outer radius $R_1$ and inner radius $R_2$ is dropped into a fluid such as water or oil. Determine how far the spherical object will sink into the fluid.

Then I found a similar problem (and its solution) in the book, *Numerical Methods Using MATLAB, Fourth Edition*:

> Consider the physical problem that involves a spherical ball of radius $r$ that is submerged to a depth $d$ in water .... Assume that the ball is constructed from a variety of longleaf pine that has a density of $\rho$ .... How much of the ball will be submerged when it is placed in water?

The solution given began as follows:

> The mass $M_w$ of water displaced when a sphere is submerged to a depth $d$ is
> $$M_w = \int_0^d \pi(r^2 - (x - r)^2) dx = \frac{\pi d^2(3r-d)}{3},$$
> and the mass of the ball is $M_b = 4 \pi r^3 \rho/3$. Applying Archimedes' law, $M_w = M_b$, produces the following equation that must be solved:
> $$\frac{\pi(d^3 - 3d^2r + 4r^3\rho)}{3} = 0.$$

What I don't understand is how the formula for $M_w$ was derived. What does the integral there represent?

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Answer (score 1):

On paper, draw a circle of radius $r$ and then draw the X and Y axes so that the origin is at the $\it{bottom}$ of your circle. Starting from the X-axis, draw horizontal lines $\Delta x$ apart. Since it's really 3-D, you've made a bunch of disks whose horizontal surface area is given by the integrand for $M_w$.

Comment: Correction: Interchange X and Y above so the X-axis points upward.